# Percentage chance of calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a Button that could activate function one, function two or function three. But I want that there is a 60% chance that function one gets called from the button and a 20% chance for function two and three.
Thanks for Help!

The code =

```js
function one(){alert('one');}
function two(){alert('two');}
function three(){alert('three');}
```

```html
<button id="mybutton"></button>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Are you familiar with `Math.random()`?

Comment: nope i never used Math.random() so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript execute function by random percentage chances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268743/javascript-execute-function-by-random-percentage-chances)

Comment: @anotheruser Don't include answers in the question body.  If you want to ask a new question, then do that, but don't modify this one into a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
function activateRandom () {
    var random = Math.random(); // get a random number from 0 to 1
    if (random < 0.6) { // 60% chance to get below 0.6
        one();
    } else if (random < 0.8) { // 20% chance to go between 0.6 and 0.8
        two();
    } else { // 20% chance remaining
        three();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider clicking the check mark under the votes so people know that the question has been answered already

Comment: how can i like modify it like when i have four functions?

Comment: Change the probabilities around and add another `else if` term, essentially just extend the code.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot man! I will click the check mark when im able to do it!

Answer (score 1):

With the button, do this.

```
<button type = "button">' put name of button here' </button>
```

for random percentage, do this.

```
var rand = Math.random(0, 100)

if(rand < 'put your random percentage here') {
'what function?'
}
```

Try using that for each function.